# Event Calling from a method c#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to call Job_JobCompleted event from  this.Job.JobCompleted in SendNotification method. But this.job shows me null so I cant be able to call it. Please help me or a way to call Job_JobCompleted event by any way. Thank you

```
public override void SendNotification(string content)
{
    this.Job.JobCompleted += Job_JobCompleted;
}

void Job_JobCompleted(object sender, JobCompletionData e)
{

    //List<string> crawledUrls = new List<string>();  // List of  included URLS in c#
    //crawledUrls.Add("http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/India");
    //crawledUrls.Add("http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/UK");
    //crawledUrls.Add("http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/Spain");
    //crawledUrls.Add("http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/Nigeria");
    //crawledUrls.Add("http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/Uganda");

    string comment = @"sitemap-generator-url=http://www.auditmypc.com/free-sitemap-generator.asp" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                                "This sitemap was created using the free tool found here: http://www.auditmypc.com/free-sitemap-generator.asp" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                                "Audit My PC also offers free security tools to help keep you safe during internet travels";
    XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

    XElement root = new XElement("urlset",
                        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"),
                        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName),
                        new XComment(comment));

    List<XElement> ChildNodes = new List<XElement>();

    foreach (string url in e.CrawledUrls)
    {
        ChildNodes.Add(CreateXMLNode(url));
    }

    root.Add(ChildNodes);
    root.Save("d:/product.xml");
}

public static XElement CreateXMLNode(string url)
{
    XElement urlnode = new XElement("url");
    urlnode.Add(new XElement("loc", url));
    return urlnode;
}
```

Comment: Invoking an event can only be done from within the class that declared the event. See [Events Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx). You are trying to raise `JobCompleted` event of some object which you have in `Job` property. You cannot do that. Only `Job` object can raise this event. What should trigger this event?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameter expected by this event Job_JobCompleted(object sender, JobCompletionData e), in sender pass the button name which is raising that event and in e pass new EventArgs, it should be like that Job_JobCompleted(btn, new EventArgs())

Answer (score 0):

with the code

```
this.Job.JobCompleted += Job_JobCompleted;
```

you simply hook up the event. You're not invoking the event. Rework your code and place your 'hookup' somewhere else (mostly of the time when you would create the job)

```
public void StartupJob()
{
    this.Job = new Job(#params); //create the object
    this.Job.JobCompleted += Job_JobCompleted; //hookup the event
    this.Job.Run(); //do some work
}

public override void SendNotification(string content)
{
    //Invoke your event (always see if it is hooked up)
    if(Job.JobCompleted != null)
        Job.JobCompleted(this, new JobCompletionData(content));
}
```

I don't know how your JobCompletionData looks like but it probably has a constructor...